# Trying to Get Control During RadGrid Insert

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a simple grid to display some comments. Here is the GridBoundColumn;

```
                                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn
                                    DataField="Comment"
                                    UniqueName="Comment"
                                    HeaderText="Comment"
                                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                    ItemStyle-Width="170px"
                                    HeaderStyle-Width="105px">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

I've captured the OnInsertCommand and I need to get the new value for the Comment field.

```
protected void rgvComments_OnInsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
```

{

```
clsShortageComment thisClass = new clsShortageComment();

GridEditableItem editableItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
Hashtable values = new Hashtable();
editableItem.ExtractValues(values);
RadTextBox theBox = editableItem.FindControl("Comment") as RadTextBox;

thisClass.Comment = theBox.Text;
thisClass.Employee = rtbEmployee.Text;
thisClass.Active = true;
thisClass.MaterialReq = Convert.ToInt32(rlbMaterial.SelectedItem.Value);
thisClass.InsertRecord();
```

}    // rgvComments_OnInsertCommand() ...

The problem is the FindControl to get the RadTextBox comes up null. I can see the Comment field in the hash table, but how do I get the value?

Answer (score 0):

I found the right syntax. I'm posting it here in case someone runs across this problem in the future.

```
protected void rgvComments_OnInsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridEditableItem editableItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
    TextBox theBox = editableItem["Comment"].Controls[0] as TextBox;
    //...
}
```